# Mysql GROUP BY multiple clauses

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| media_id   | title        | artist            | plays             |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        100 | Song A       |              Jack |    6              |
|         35 | Song B       |           Suzzane |    33             |
|         73 | Song C       |              Anne |    2              |
|         50 | Song D       |            Jonnie |    7              |
|         50 | Song F       |            Jonnie |    123            |
|         50 | Song G       |            Jonnie |    39             |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I am running this query (notice artist 'Jonnie' has same media_id)

```
SELECT media_id, artist, title, SUM(plays) AS total_plays
FROM table
GROUP BY media_id, artist, title
ORDER BY total_count
```

This query works fine, but my question is can I group by media_id those records that have unique media_id, while group by media_id, artist, title those records that have same media_id (Jonnie in this example)

Comment: Can you provide expected results? It's not totally clear what you're asking here.

Comment: If you mean you want groups to be grouped by media_id if the group only has one row, then the result will be exactly the same as if you use `GROUP BY media_id, artist, title`, because the group only has one row, therefore one value of `artist` and `title` anyway. So You can use the query as you show above in your question. If you mean something else, you should show a mockup of the result you want to see given the data shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT z.media_id, z.artist, z.title, z.plays as "Total Plays by Title", b.total_plays as "total plays by artist"
FROM `playstable` z
inner join (select y.media_id,  SUM(y.plays) AS total_plays from `playstable` y  GROUP BY y.media_id ) b on z.media_id=b.media_id;
```